# Pokemon go, all progress lost, no sign in option

Tags: pokemon-go

I got signed out of Pokemon go and when I logged back on it had a whole new account, Ive realised Its not actually giving me the option to sign in, only sign up? Does anyone know how I can get the option to sign in back? I've tried deleting the app and redownloading it, turning the phone off etc, I can't work it out! I have it on iPhone with all the latest updates working

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to delete the app. Remove any saved google passwords on your phone, then re-install:

Details here: https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/224047008

Answer (score -3):

Just login with your APPLE ACCOUNT in Pokemon GO ,this works like a charm for Apple Users.

Comment: The Apple ID isn't associated with your Pokemon account at all. Perhaps you've used the same e-mail address for both, but that doesn't mean they're inherently linked. I've just tried signing to Pokemon GO with my Apple ID email, and it prompted me to make a new account (as it hasn't been used before).